# How to load a RGB format texture from memory using dx?

Tags: c++, directx, textures, rgb

Here is my trying

```
in = cvLoadImage("24bpp_1920x1200_1.bmp", 1);

HRESULT err;
IDirect3DTexture9 * texture = NULL;
///D3DFMT_L8, D3DFMT_R8G8B8
err = D3DXCreateTexture(g_pd3dDevice, in->width, in->height, 1, 0 , D3DFMT_R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_MANAGED, &g_pTexture);
D3DLOCKED_RECT lockRect;
RECT rect;

err = g_pTexture->LockRect(0, &lockRect, NULL, 0);//I have specified the format is RGB, then why does lockRect.Picth = 7680?

memcpy(lockRect.pBits, in->imageData, in->widthStep*in->height);
if(FAILED(g_pTexture->UnlockRect(0))) 
{
    ///
}
```

It can't display an image in RGB format. But it can display an image in grayscale or in RGBA format.

Otherwise, I want to display high resolution image like the sample of displaying image using d3d in Dx Sdk_june10".\DXSDK\Samples\InstalledSamples\Textures" does.
But, again, it can't display an image in size more than 1920x1200px approximately.

How to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to keep in mind:

(1) You need to check for caps that indicates support for the 24-bpp format. Not every Direct3D 9 device supports it.

(2) You have to respect the pitch returned by LockRect, so you need to do the copy scan-line by scan-line, so you can't do the whole thing in just one memcpy. Something like:

```
BYTE* sptr = in->imageData;
BYTE* dptr = lockRect.pBits;
for( int y = 0; y < in->height; ++y )
{
    memcpy( dptr, sptr, in->widthStep );
    sptr += in->widthStep;
    dptr += lockRect.Pitch;
}
```

This assumes `in->widthStep` is the pitch of the source image in bytes, that `in->widthStep` is <= `lockRect.Pitch`, and that the format of the source image is identical to the format of the Direct3D resource.

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't work on my PC. Why can you copy entire row of src image to dst image? As I know, the 4bytes pixel format looks like [dst_r][dst_g][dst_b][dst_a] in big endian or little endian. In this case, if I directly copy 2 pixels of src image in RGB format to dst image in RGBA format, the first 2 pixels of dst image will become [src_r1][src_g1][src_b1][src_r2]  [src_g2][src_b2][src_r3][src_g3] respectively.

Comment: ``memcpy(lockRect.pBits, in->imageData, in->widthStep*in->height);`` is not copying a row. It's attempting to copy the entire image in one go. You have to do scanline-by-scanline copies because you don't get to set the pitch of the Direct3D resource.

Comment: Also, have you verified your ``err`` is from D3DXCreateTexture is in fact ``SUCCEEDED(err)``?  Remember that ``D3DXCreateTexture`` is free to return a different D3DFORMAT texture (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172800.aspx)) so you need to check the value of ``D3DSURFACE_DESC desc; texture->GetLevelDesc(0, &desc);`` to ensure ``desc.Format`` actually came back as ``D3DFMT_R8G8B8``. If the hardware doesn't support it, it might not actually match your source image format. If so, this would require something besides a simple ``memcpy`` for each scanline.

Comment: All HRESULT values are S_OK.

Comment: All HRESULT values are S_OK. I use DXCapsViewer.exe to check all formats my graphics card supported. Though it has D3DFMT_R8G8B8 format showed in "Direct3D9 Devices->NVIDIA GeForce GT 620->HAL->Adapter Formats->D3DFMT_R8G8B8", I can't find D3DFMT_R8G8B8 into this item in the advanced detailed items, and I guess that this means my graphics card looks RGB as RGBA format, so that I use D3DFMT_R8G8B8 to CreateTexture without an error. I can only copy pixels from src image to dst image pixel by pixel.